# Informatica target file

Tags: informatica

I have a workflow which writes data from a table into a flatfile. It works just fine, but I want to insert a blank line inbetween each records. How can this be achieved ? Any pointer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you can create 2 target instances. One with the proper data and in other instance pass blank line. Set Merge Type as "**Concurrent Merge**" in session properties.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple possibilities -

1. You can prepare appropriate dataset into a relational table, and afterwards, dump data from that into a flat file.  For preparation of that data set, you can insert blank rows into that relational target.
2. Send a blank line to a separate target file (based on some business condition using a router or something similar), after that you can use merge files option (in session config) to get that data into a single file.